# Isomorphic to external sum $\implies$ is internal direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

A module $M$ is an internal direct sum of submodules $N_{1},\dots,N_{k}$ iff for all $m \in M$, there exists unique $n_{1} \in N_{1}, \dots, n_{k} \in N_{k}$ such that $m = n_{1}+n_{2}+\dots+n_{k}$

> Now given a module $M$, and modules $N_{1}, N_{2}, \dots,N_{k} \subset M$, if $M$ isomorphic to the external direct sum of $N_{1}, \dots,N_{k}$, is $M$ the internal direct sum of $N_{1},\dots,N_{k}$?

I think if the isomorphism is $f(n_{1},\dots ,n_{k}) = n_{1} + \dots + n_{k}$ this is easy to prove. However, what if the isomorphism is defined differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true in general.  Consider $\mathbb Z$-modules $M=\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$, $N_1=2\mathbb Z\oplus \{0\}$, and $N_2=\{0\}\oplus 2\mathbb Z$.

Then $(a,b)\mapsto ((2a,0), (0,2b))$ gives an isomorphism $M\cong N_1\oplus N_2$, but $N_1+N_2=2\mathbb Z\oplus 2\mathbb Z\neq M$.

Comment: Thank you, so just to make sure $N_{1} \oplus N_{2} = 2\mathbb{Z} \times2\mathbb{Z}$, where we can interpret $\oplus$ as the inteneral direct sum. However, $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong 2\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$. So if I change the word "is" internal direct sum to "is isomorphic to" internal direct sum, does this hold?

Comment: Sorry, I was your edits after I wrote the comments, so if we change the word from "is" to "is isomorphic to", is it true?

Comment: In general, "the" internal direct sum of $N_1,\dots,N_k$ is not always a real thing.  That is, one can talk about the submodule $N:=N_1+\dots +N_k$, but typically  $N$ will not be the internal direct sum.  However, in the special case that it ***is*** an internal direct sum, $N$ will also be isomorphic to the external direct sum, via the isomorphism you mentioned in your post $f((n_1,\dots,n_k))=n_1+\dots+n_k$.

Comment: @M W Yeah, but suppose N is the internal direct sum, is it always isomorphic to M?

Comment: If $M$ is isomorphic to the external direct sum, then since an internal direct sum is always isomorphic to the external direct sum, yes, the two would be isomorphic.

Comment: @M W Yeah of course, by assumption M is isomorphic to the external direct sum. Thank you.