# Completely reducible means it is the internal direct sum of subrepresentations?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I was reading a lecture notes on finite group representation theory, and it mentioned the following:

If $\phi: G \rightarrow G L(V)$ is a representation, and $V_1, \ldots, V_n \leq V$ are $G$-invariant subspaces, and if $V$ is an internal direct sum of these subspaces, then we say we say that $\phi$ is an internal direct sum of the subrepresentations $\left.\phi\right|_{V_k}$. In this case, there is an equivalence of representations $\left(\left.\phi\right|_{V_1}\right) \oplus \cdots \oplus\left(\left.\phi\right|_{V_n}\right) \sim \phi$ between $\phi$ and the external direct sum built from the subrepresentations.

We say that $\phi: G \rightarrow G L(V)$ is decomposable if it is an internal direct sum of two non-0 invariant subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$. (I.e., both $V_1$ and $V_2$ have positive dimensions.)

We say that $\phi: G \rightarrow G L(V)$ is completely reducible if it is equivalent to a direct sum of a finite sequence of irreducible subrepresentations.

> I wonder if completely reducible means that it is the internal direct sum of the subrepresentations of $\phi_{V_{k}}$. I felt that $\phi|_{V_{1}} \oplus \dots \oplus \phi|_{V_{n}} \sim \phi$ does not necessarily mean that $\phi$ is the internal direct sum, as the specific equivalence is not specified, or does it?

Comment: Internal or external does not matter here, as they are essentially the same thing

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry can you elaborate? Why is the equivalent to an external direct sum the same as being an internal direct sum in this context?

Comment: Not just in this context. The two things really are the same in every way that matters. You should convince yourself of that (start with the simple example of just vector spaces if that is easier)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can you elaborate on what you mean by the same? I posted [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810470/isomorphic-to-external-sum-implies-is-internal-direct-sum) before, and I felt they are different.

Comment: If $M$ is isomorphic to the external direct sum $\bigoplus N_i$, then under that isomorphism you can identify the $N_i$s with submodules of $M$, and then $M$ is an internal direct sum of those submodules. And vice-versa. This is a special case of a general phenomena called "transport of structure." The linked question has the $N_i$ be submodules that are *different* from the ones the isomorphism $M\cong\bigoplus N_i$ transports them to, so $M$ isn't an internal direct sum of those "wrong" copies of the $N_i$s.

Comment: @coiso Thank you. So by identity, you mean taking the image of $N_i$ for the isomorphism right?

Comment: "Identify," yes.